# Like doesnt work with Doctrine 2 raw query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

the working version:

```
->getConnection()->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM x WHERE word LIKE "%|'.$keyword.'%"');
```

it does work but not prepared, SQL injections are possible.

```
->getConnection()->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM x WHERE word LIKE :keyword', ['keyword' => "%|".$keyword."%"']);
```

it should work though wont return anything.

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: You have syntax error. Try with `['keyword' => '%|'.$keyword.'%']`. Or is it a typo in the question only?

Comment: @dragoste I edited, it was just a typo

Comment: @Alok the 2nd returns with empty array

Comment: Then please check final runnable SQL query in Symfony's profiler and validate if it's what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Why the pipe symbol?  Still think you probably have a syntax error.  Try 'keyword' => '%something%' and see if you get the expected results.

Comment: @dragoste oups, I dont have that, its not that framework

Comment: @Cerad this is there on purpose.

Comment: Then you've put incorrect tags in your question. ;-) Anyway, check, what exact query is run.

Comment: @dragoste:  Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Statement::getSql()

Comment: SELECT * FROM x WHERE word LIKE :keyword
----
Params: ["%|'budape%"]